# Canon MG4250 all in one doesn't find my linux pc

Tags: drivers, printer, linux-mint, canon-pixma

I am a beginner in Linux and I start to like it a lot. I know I have to try and document before asking questions. So here is the problem and what I already did.

Hardware: 
Hp laptop with Mint installed. Ip 192.168.1.107
Canon MG4250 Printer. Ip 192.168.1.207
Router Linksys E3000 + dd-wrt on it. Ip 192.168.1.1

Issue: 
My printer installed well with the GUI. Driver installed and test page printed. So from laptop to printer all ok. Now when I try to scan something on the Canon machine and I want to sent it to the Linux laptop, it doesn't find my linux machine. It worked with Win7, the OS preceding Linux. So from the Canon printer, scan to the laptop Mint = no success.

Already done: 
1/ Installed drivers. It was a file named: iP4200_Linux_260.tar.gz (unzipped it and did the necessary in command line). 
2/ Made a shared folder on my Mint laptop, because I thought it could be a Samba problem. Was not the solution.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: Max - welcome to the site.  Great question and answer.  You're only 2 rep away from being able to post your own answer, which you should definitely do.  Split off the answer into an actual answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: BTW, on the last sentence in your post: the scan button on the printer often relies on the (Windows) drivers or software that came with the printer.  Often, that feature isn't supported by the Linux drivers.  You may have the option of several different Linux scan applications.  Try them all to see if any one supports the on-printer button.

Comment: Thx fixer1234! for your advice concerning "how to post my answer" :-)

Comment: Max - you should have waited until you had 2 more rep to split off the answer (ask an upvoted question= +5, suggest an edit that is approved to improve another question= +2).  Doing your answer as a community wiki you don't get any rep for the answer (but it demonstrates your altruism ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE + SOLUTION!!

It was not necessary anymore to post this. But I'd like to share my solution in case someone bumps into the same issue.

I came across this site: http://robert.penz.name/532/a-howto-for-using-a-canon-pixma-mg4250-under-ubuntu/#comments

So all credits go to this person :-). I'll quickly type the steps to follow in case his page disappears one day.

1/ First download the software/drivers on this site: http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100470302.html
This is the Asian site from Canon. Apparently you won't find it on the US or EU site.

2/ Extract the tar.gz and go into the newly created directory.

$ tar xzf scangearmp-mg4200series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz
$ cd scangearmp-mg4200series-2.00-1-deb/

3/ Use the install script.

$ ./install.sh

4/ After the installation just start the scanning program.

$ scangearmp

It will show you an error message that no configured scanner has been detected, click Ok.

In case that the first start list is empty, you need to click onto “Update Scanner List”, after this you should see the same window with your printer.

Click "ok" and you are in the GUI program.

I tested it and what this program does is, it goes the other way around. In staid of you standing in front of your Canon printer searching for any pc on the wireless network, it is your pc that is contacting the Cannon printer (through that software you just started) and he will give you a preview of what lays under the scan lid!! You'll have the possibility of course to save this preview. And 'voila'. You have your scan ready in the folder you choose to save it.

Just to check: I tried again to scan from the Canon printer and sent it to a pc. The result was still the same: he didn't find any pc to sent to.